# How to perform synchronization in android?

Tags: android, asynchronous

I referred so many links regarding synchronization

> http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html
>
> my requirement is to download all the data regarding the user at first time.There are nearly 12 tables are existed at the service i need to download all the 12 table into the android mobile at first time.  After that we will modify that local data whenever we click on that sync button we need to send that updated data to the server.
>
> I am following this type of approach: I am sending a json object to android mobile from server side which contains all the 12 tables data.by using that json object i create the tables and insert those data into the local database.Is this correct approach?
>
> Is there any jars exists to simplify this type of requirements?

Please give any suggestions regarding this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For downloading the data. You can use `AsyncTask` in Android. Its runs at background so no worry if you are changing the `UI`. Here is the documentation

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

Here is the good tutorial on this topic have a look on this

[Android Background Processing with Handlers and AsyncTask and Loaders - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: i know about asynctask functionality..is there any why without converting the entire data to json and transfer ?

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this you can use `Webservices` for this. And can you be specific how do you mean by `without converting the entire data to json and transfer `? `JSON` is good its light weight and suits for mobile. you can also do it with `XML` you can refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799797/what-is-a-web-service-in-android